Partition by column value in O(n)
Using polars, can I reorder the rows of a dataframe such that

Rows with equal value in col1 appear contiguously
Doing this is an O(n) operation.

An alternative way of phrasing this is that I want the output sorted by some arbitrary order of col1, but I don't care which order, which should reduce the runtime from O(nlogn) to O(n).
Using this slightly awkward rephrasing I can ask the actual question I'm ultimately after: can I reorder the rows of a dataframe such that the output is sorted lexicographically by (col1, ..., colN), with some arbitrary order of (col1,..., colM) and the canonical order of (colM+1, ..., colN), other than via sorting (which would pick the canonical order of (col1, ..., colM) and would require unnecessary work)?
A simple example would be: I have rows (Date, String, Int) containing yearly population data of different cities over the last century. I want the rows for each given city next to each other and sorted by year (say, because I'm using an external tool for postprocessing that requires contiguity) but I don't care whether Amsterdam comes before Berlin.
Theoretically, this is trivially achievable in O(n) using hashes. Practically, I'd need built-in polars operations for this to be faster than just a regular sort.
EDIT: Timings of solutions suggested so far to my first question (partition rows, don't necessarily order them), far on an example with M=1, N=2 and 10M rows and average group size 10:



Method
Time




SORT
0.26s (2)


EXPLODE
0.22s (1)


PARTITION
3.89s (3)



where

SORT just sorts by (col1, col2)
EXPLODE uses the suggestion by @BallpointBen, df.group_by("col1").all().explode(pl.exclude("col1"))
PARTITION uses the suggestion by @Dogbert, pl.concat(df.partition_by("col1"))

Timings of solutions suggested so far to my second question (partition rows and order within partition by second column), far on an example with M=1, N=2 and 1M rows and average group size 10:



Method
Presorted




SORT
0.03s (1)


PARTITION
5.05s (3)


PARALLELPARTITION
1.49s (2)



where

SORT just sorts by (col1, col2)
PARTITION uses the suggestion by @Dogbert, pl.concat([x.sort('col2') for x in df.partition_by("col1")])
PARALLELPARTITION uses the suggestion by @DeanMcGregor, pl.concat([x.lazy().sort('col2') for x in df.partition_by("col1")]).collect()


I wonder if you could group_by by key column, aggregate data into lists and then explode? I’m on mobile so can’t test it. It could be faster than sorting (not sure about implode/explode performance though)

You could also give df.group_by(partition_cols).head(df.height) a try.

Not sure if this is the most efficient, but df.group_by("col1", ..., "colM").all().explode(pl.exclude("col1", ..., "colM")) will group into lists and then explode them back into a long df.
To also sort by other columns within groups, you can do:
cols = ["col1", ..., "colM"]
(
    df.group_by(cols)
    .all()
    .explode(pl.exclude(cols))
    .with_columns(pl.exclude(cols).sort().over(cols))
    .collect()
)


Is there a way to sort by colM+1,...,colN with this? (Or even just by a single colM+1)

(This is far faster on my data than the partition_by solutions, for the first question that I asked but I feel like there is no way to combine it with within-group sorting)

@Bananach see my edit

Amazing. (Minor nitpick: I had to replace sort by sort_by(["colM+1", ...., "colN"]) because otherwise each column is sorted individually and the rows are garbled up, which is a grievance I always seem to run into with polars)

Sadly, even as #rows -> infinity, this solution seems to still be 2x slower than a global sort in my problem. Still, great answer!

You can use DataFrame.partition_by to split the dataframe into a separate dataframe for each value in an arbitrary order, then call pl.concat on the list of dataframes. Theoretically this should be O(n).
In my tests, for large dataframes and a low-cardinality column to partition by, this is faster than sorting.
This is an example where the partition column has 100 unique values:
import timeit

import numpy as np
import polars as pl

for size in [100_000, 1_000_000, 10_000_000]:
    df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "foo": np.random.randint(0, 100, size),
            "bar": np.random.randint(0, 1_000_000, size),
        }
    )

    print(size)
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: df.sort("foo"), number=10))
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: pl.concat(df.partition_by("foo")), number=10))

Output:
100000
0.01896386011503637
0.012146126013249159
1000000
0.3261005349922925
0.08920360007323325
10000000
4.747504440136254
1.4530502599664032

But, if the cardinality of the column is large, e.g. if you split by bar which has upto 1 million partitions, this is extremely slow.

Thanks for the good suggestion. Unfortunately, in my example I have a high cardinality column to partition by (this is where I hope the savings are: the sort within each partition is only 8 rows on average whereas the total dataframe is millions of rows).

try pl.concat([x.lazy().sort('bar') for x in df.partition_by("foo")]).collect() as that'll do all the sub sorts in parallel. I don't know enough about the algorithms to know what the BigO notation is of that. I suppose bringing parallelism into it makes the BigO notation not really the right metric.

Thanks, I'll try this and a to other suggestions and report back the timings

@deanmacgregor Lazy helps, but doesn't get anywhere close as fast as a regular sort

Wish I could accept both answers. Ended up accepting the other answer because it stays purely in polars.
